CSS and Scripts bundles not working properly in header after dividing into layouts; .NET Framework
Before dividing into layouts and creating the header, everything was working. Then i created different layouts and header, and then bundles, but they are not loading properly. The site is launching but, there are no blank spaces on sides, and the script for "settings" and "cart" buttons are not working.
I am using a template. Github link - https://github.com/user9450/Proiect-MRSUTWeb
_LayoutWithoutUser.cshtml file
@using System.Web.Optimization

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title>Limupa Shop</title>

<!--Google Fonts-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900">

<!— Favicon —>
<link href="~/Content/images/favicon.png" rel="icon">

<!--Vendor CSS Files-->
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/material-design-iconic-font/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/font-awesome/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/font-awesome-stars/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/meanmenu/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/owl-carousel/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/slick/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/animate/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/jquery-ui/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/venobox/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/nice-select/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/magnific-popup/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/bootstrap/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/helper/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/responsive/css")

IsSectionDefined("Styles")
{
@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
}

<!--Main CSS File-->
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/style/css")
</head>

<body>

<div class="body-wrapper">

<!--Header-->
<header class="li-header-4">
@Html.Partial("_HeaderWithoutUser")
</header>

<!--Main Content-->
<div class="static-top-wrap">
@RenderBody()
</div>

<!--Footer-->
<div class="footer">
@Html.Partial("_Footer")
</div>

<!--Vendor JS Files-->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/popper/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-1.12.4/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr-2.8.3/js")

<!--Other-->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scrollUp/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/venobox/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ajax-mail/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-nice-select/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-ui/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-barrating/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/waypoints/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-counterup/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-countdown/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-mixitup/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/imagesloaded-pkgd/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/isotope-pkgd/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/magnific-popup/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/owl-carousel/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/slick/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/wow/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-meanmenu/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/popper/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-1.12.4/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-validate/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-3.7.1/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-3.7.1-min/js")

<!— Template Main JS File —>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main/js")

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</div>
</body>
</html>


I checked the console in developer tools, it showed 3 errors: JQuery is not defined and some bootstrap files not loading. I fixed them by swaping the @Scripts.Render commands, but nothing changed. I checked the spelling and if every file is used, and everything should work.
This is my first university project, and is required using .NET Framework.
